# VBA Sumproduct on Array Columns

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Is there a way in Excel VBA to use Application.WorksheetFunction.Sumproduct to get the sumproduct of 2 array columns?  For example, if A and B are two arrays each with 3 rows and 3 columns (VBA arrays, not Excel arrays), is there an easy way to get the sumproduct of the 3rd column of A with the 2nd column of B? If so, what is the syntax?
Thanks

Comment: What are VBA arrays? Arrays of arrays or really 2D-arrays?

Comment: please try to visualize your question so we can understand better what your asking

Answer (score 2):

While it might be tempting to try and use `WorksheetFunction.SumProduct` to do this, looping over a VBA array will be *much* faster than using worksheet functions.  In a small test I got about a **x40** performance improvement over the other posted answer.

This is a simple example of how you might do it.  You should add validity checks on the inputs and error handling.

```
Function ArraySumProduct(aA As Variant, aB As Variant, col1 As Long, col2 As Long) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dSumProduct

    For i = LBound(aA) To UBound(aA)
        dSumProduct = dSumProduct + aA(i, col1) * aB(i, col2)
    Next
    ArraySumProduct = dSumProduct
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems as if WorksheetFunction.Index works with arrays of arrays also. So you can achieve this with a combination of WorksheetFunction.Index to get the 3rd and 2nd columns and WorksheetFunction.Transpose to get 1D-arrays of the columns and then WorksheetFunction.SumProduct.

```
Sub test()

 aA = [{1,2, 3;4,5, 6;7,8, 9}]
 aB = [{10, 11,12;13, 14,15;16, 17,18}]

 'aA = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6), Array(7, 8, 9))
 'aB = Array(Array(10, 11, 12), Array(13, 14, 15), Array(16, 17, 18))

 aCol3of_aA = WorksheetFunction.Index(aA, 0, 3)
 aCol2of_aB = WorksheetFunction.Index(aB, 0, 2)

 aArr1 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aCol3of_aA)
 aArr2 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aCol2of_aB)

 dSumProduct = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(aArr1, aArr2)
 '= 3*11 + 6*14 + 9*17 = 270

 MsgBox dSumProduct

End Sub
```