# What is the Best Method for Storing Data

Tags: arrays, database, excel, ms-word, vba

I am creating a Word userform using VBA. I store several configuration using array in the program code, such as the following:

```
Public arrConfiguration[2, 3] as Integer
```

where index 2 represent type 0 to 2, and index 3 represent properties 0 to 3 for each type.

However, I planned to modify the program for larger amount of data (such as for 100 different types of data and 50 properties for each data).
My question is,
should I keep storing the data using array in the program, so that it will be

```
Public arrConfiguration[99, 49] as Integer
```

or store it in an Excel file, and make the program open the Excel file and access the cells repeatedly? Which one is better?

Thank you.

Comment: Hope you have gone through the additional information  and found it useful. For your query regarding array elements multiplication please go through the link VBA sum products of array columns <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373280/vba-sumproduct-on-array-columns/27374474#27374474>. It clearly demonstrates the right way of doing things. If you are satisfied , please accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please prefer excel. Sample example data image is appended here-under.

- For cre­at­ing two dimen­sional dynamic array in excel, fol­low the steps below:

◾Declare the two dimen­sional Array

◾Resize the array

◾Store val­ues in array

◾Retrieve val­ues from array

[image: Array sample example]

```
Sub FnTwoDimentionDynamic()

   Dim arrTwoD()

   Dim intRows

   Dim intCols

    intRows = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    intCols = Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count

     ReDim Preserve arrTwoD(1 To intRows, 1 To intCols)

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrTwoD, 1)

      For j = 1 To UBound(arrTwoD, 2)

    arrTwoD(i, j) = Sheet1.Cells(i, j)

      Next

   Next

   MsgBox "The value is B5 is " & arrTwoD(5, 2)

End Sub
```

In the Message Box you will get the following output.

[image]

Further To visualize a two dimensional array we could picture a row of CD racks. To make things easier, we can imagine that each CD rack could be for a different artist. Like the CDs, the racks would be identifiable by number. Below we'll define a two dimensional array representing a row of CD racks. The strings inside of the array will represent album titles.

[image: 2D Array Illustration]

For multidimensional arrays it should be noted that only the last dimension can be resized. That means that given our example above, once we created the array with two CD racks, we would not be able to add more racks, we would only be able to change the number of CDs each rack held.

Comment: According to your answer, I store the data in Excel and then copy it to the arrTwoD before using the data for the next process, right? I'm wondering why should I do that rather than directly access the cells for the next process. For example, why should I use: `MsgBox "The value of B5 is " & arrTwoD (5,2)` instead of `MsgBox "The value of B5 is " & Sheet1.Cells(5, 2)`?

Comment: MsgBox part is only to demonstrate that code is functionally correct. It is for test purposes only. Once array is populated you can directly use it by its elements such as `arrTwoD(i, j)`  for further processing. Another point is how are you going to populate array. Array values are to be fed either manually or from some data source.

Comment: I think I didn't make my question clear. I understand that the MsgBox is only for demonstrating the result. My point is, are there any difference (in terms of efficiency, etc) between (1) access the excel cell then directly use the value for the next process (such as: `a = Sheet1.Cells(1,2) + Sheet1.Cells(1,3)`) and (2) access the excel cell, store the value in an array (such as arrTwoD) then use the value in array for the next process (such as: `a=arrTwoD(1,2) + arrTwoD(1,3)`)?

Comment: @loremipsum It is better to process through Array and still better through Dictionary. In order to have better appreciation , please go though this example:<http://1drv.ms/1QcKvwX> This example utilize excel, array and dictionary approach. Just clear the contents of Result field in Column T , Then click the command button. Result field will be filled based on match of three criteria fields. Go through the code which is simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify @skkakkar code:

```
dim x as variant
x = range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

No `Redim`, no loops.

Comment: Good Suggestion. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you see things evolving, you might want to consider accessing your Excel data via ADO, rather than OLE Automation. That way, if you decide to change your storage system to Access, SQL Server or something else, you will have less work to do.

**How To Use ADO with Excel Data from Visual Basic or VBA** (Microsoft)
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/257819

**Read and Write Excel Documents Using OLEDB** (Codeproject)
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/705470/Read-and-Write-Excel-Documents-Using-OLEDB